# How do you set the content size of a UIPopoverController?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm showing a view in a popover. When I click a button in this view, another view will be pushed into the popover using a navigation controller.  While pushing, the height of the popover gets extended.  How do I retain the same popover height?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In all your view controllers, override `-contentSizeForViewInPopover` and return the same size in all of them.

Comment: Just to make it clear, in the view controller that provides whats inside the popover you need to override the     `-contentSizeForViewInPopover`

Comment: While correct previous to iOS 7, this is now deprecated and no longer works in iOS 8.1. See the alternate answer.

Answer (score 2):

-contentSizeForViewInPopover is deprecated as of iOS 7, and does not seem to work in iOS 8.1. (I'm not sure when it stopped working.) The new method is to set the preferredContentSize, perhaps like this:

```
    MyPopoverViewController *myPopoverViewController = [[MyPopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyPopoverViewController" bundle: nil];
    myPopoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(186, 160);

    self.myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: myPopoverViewController];
    myPopover.delegate = self;

    [myPopover presentPopoverFromRect: self.myButton.frame inView: self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated: YES];
```